# How to setDate of the datepicker with button click without loosing beforeshowDay propertys?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, datepicker

i have a script which can make just some dates selectable with beforeShowDay and when you click on one of these dates a partial view will be opened and some data is shown. With the two buttons "back" and "forth" the data, which is shown in the partial view, change depending on the date.

But the inline datepicker isnt updating, the date which i first selected is still selected, but it should change to the next selectable date. Do you know how to change the script to archieve that?

I tried to set the Date with setDate but nothing i tried worked. Often he forgot all dates that should be selectable or jumped to 2021... Probably i used it wrong...

my **view** look like this:

```
Date: <div class="datepicker"></div>

<div id="month""></div> // partial view area

<input  id="Back" type="button" value="Back" style ="display:none"/>     
<input  id="Forth" type="button" value="Forth" style ="display:none" />
```

the **script** looks like that:

```
 var dateObject
 var array = @Html.Raw(jsonObject)    

 $(function () {
     $(".datepicker").datepicker({
         numberOfMonths: 3,
         dateFormat: 'dd-m-yy',           
         beforeShowDay: function (date) {
        if ($.inArray($.datepicker.formatDate('yy-m-d', date), array) > -1) {
            return [true, "", " yes"];
        }
        else {
            return [false, "", "no"];
        }
         },
         onSelect: function () {

             var CID = parseInt(@ViewBag.CID);
             var IID = parseInt(@ViewBag.IID);
             var EID = parseInt(@ViewBag.EID);
             dateObject = $.datepicker.formatDate("yy-m-d", $(this).datepicker("getDate"));
             $('#Back').show();
             $('#Forth').show();
             $('#month').load('/History/IndexPartial?id=' + dateObject + '&EID=' + EID + '&CID=' + CID + '&IID=' + IID);
         }
     });

     $("#Back").click(function () {
         arraylenght = array.length;
         for (i = 0; i < arraylenght; i++) {
             if (array[i] == dateObject && i!=0)
             {
                 dateObject = array[i-1];
                 break;            
             }
         }
         var CID = parseInt(@ViewBag.CID);
         var IID = parseInt(@ViewBag.IID);
         var EID = parseInt(@ViewBag.EID);
         $('#month').load('/History/IndexPartial?id=' + dateObject + '&EID=' + EID + '&CID=' + CID + '&IID=' + IID);

     });        

     $("#Forth").click(function () {
         arraylenght = array.length;
         for (i = 0; i < arraylenght; i++) {
             if (array[i] == dateObject && i!= arraylenght-1) {
                 dateObject = array[i + 1];
                 break;
             }
         }
         var CID = parseInt(@ViewBag.CID);
         var IID = parseInt(@ViewBag.IID);
         var EID = parseInt(@ViewBag.EID);
         $('#month').load('/History/IndexPartial?id=' + dateObject + '&EID=' + EID + '&CID=' + CID + '&IID=' + IID);
     });

 });
```

And my controller looks like this:

```
    public ActionResult Index(int EID = 0, int CID = 0, int IID= 0)
    {
        ViewBag.CID = CID;
        ViewBag.IID = IID;
        ViewBag.EID = EID;

        var historydates = db.Histories.Where(p => p.ESiteId == EID && p.CId == CID && p.IId == IID).OrderBy(s=> s.Date).Select(p => 
                SqlFunctions.DateName("yy", p.Date) + "-" +
                SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)
                SqlFunctions.DatePart("mm", p.Date)).Trim() + "-" +
                SqlFunctions.DateName("dd", p.Date)).ToList();

        return View(historydates);
    }

    public PartialViewResult IndexPartial(DateTime? id, int EID, int CID, int IID)
    {
        ViewBag.Date = id;
        ViewBag.CID = CID;
        ViewBag.IID = IID;
        ViewBag.EID = EID;

        var model = db.Histories.Where(p => p.ESiteId == EID && p.CId == CID && p.IId == IID && p.Date == id).First();
        return PartialView("_IndexPartial", model);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the current selected date from datepicker using "getDate" method. After that, you can find next date in array (using $.inArray) and assign that  to datepicker using "setDate" method.

JavaScript:

```
var dateObject
var array = @Html.Raw(jsonObject)    

$(function () {
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 3,
        dateFormat: 'dd-m-yy',           
        beforeShowDay: function (date) {
    if ($.inArray($.datepicker.formatDate('yy-m-d', date), array) > -1) {
        return [true, "", " yes"];
    }
    else {
        return [false, "", "no"];
    }
        },
        onSelect: function () {

            var CID = parseInt(@ViewBag.CID);
            var IID = parseInt(@ViewBag.IID);
            var EID = parseInt(@ViewBag.EID);
            dateObject = $.datepicker.formatDate("yy-m-d", $(this).datepicker("getDate"));
            $('#Back').show();
            $('#Forth').show();
            $('#month').load('/History/IndexPartial?id=' + dateObject + '&EID=' + EID + '&CID=' + CID + '&IID=' + IID);
        }
    });

    $("#Back").click(function () {
        var currDate = $('.datepicker').datepicker("getDate");
        var currDateIndex = $.inArray($.datepicker.formatDate('yy-m-d', currDate), array);

        // Boundary Condition
        if(currDateIndex > 0) 
        {
            var CID = parseInt(@ViewBag.CID);
            var IID = parseInt(@ViewBag.IID);
            var EID = parseInt(@ViewBag.EID);
            $('#month').load('/History/IndexPartial?id=' + array[currDateIndex-1] + '&EID=' + EID + '&CID=' + CID + '&IID=' + IID);
            $(".datepicker").datepicker("setDate",new Date(array[currDateIndex-1]));
        }
    });        

    $("#Forth").click(function () {
        var currDate = $('.datepicker').datepicker("getDate");
        var currDateIndex = $.inArray($.datepicker.formatDate('yy-m-d', currDate), array);

        // Boundary Condition
        if (currDateIndex < array.length - 1)
        {
            var CID = parseInt(@ViewBag.CID);
            var IID = parseInt(@ViewBag.IID);
            var EID = parseInt(@ViewBag.EID);
            $('#month').load('/History/IndexPartial?id=' + array[currDateIndex + 1] + '&EID=' + EID + '&CID=' + CID + '&IID=' + IID);
            $(".datepicker").datepicker("setDate", new Date(array[currDateIndex + 1]));
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Wow, you are amazing, thank you : ) ...i tried to solve it for two days or so... i would never thought about that.